# Setting NavGraph programmatically

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack

In my activity layout, I have the following `NavHostFragment`:

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav_graph" />
```

My question is how can I set the navGraph programmatically? How can I convert the `my_nav_host_fragment` view instance in a `NavHostFragment` instance?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
//Setup the navGraph for this activity
val myNavHostFragment: NavHostFragment = my_nav_host_fragment as NavHostFragment
val inflater = myNavHostFragment.navController.navInflater
val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.my_nav_graph)
myNavHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
```

Based on: [Navigation Architecture Component- Passing argument data to the startDestination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50457707/1204249)

Comment: Can you do this multiple times, setting a different graph at each time?

Comment: @Klaasel I think so.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#create_the_navhostfragment_programmatically  @amp

Comment: Yes you can @klaasel :) Thanks amp this was super helpful

Comment: I think the correct way to reference nav graph should be `R.navigation.my_nav_graph`

Answer (score 7):

You can write in your Activity as follows.

```kotlin
findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).setGraph(R.navigation.my_nav_graph)
```

Answer (score 5):

Both of the answers caused exception when i used with DynamicNavHostFragment, so i used

```
val navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
    .findFragmentById(R.id. my_nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment

navHostFragment.findNavController().setGraph(R.navigation. my_nav_graph)
```

Comment: `findNavController()` will search for controller in all child views and will return first controller, that is not null. If you have nested `nav_graph`s, your code can set graph to the wrong controller.

Answer (score 1):

**My solution is this,**

```
val myNavHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
        .findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragmentMain) as NavHostFragment
    val inflater = myNavHostFragment.navController.navInflater
    val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph)
    myNavHostFragment.navController.graph = graph
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.nav_graph);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, navHostFragment);
        transaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(navHostFragment);
        transaction.commit();
```