# How to build NavGraph programmatically with Java in Android

Tags: java, android, navigation

I know it is easy to build a NavGraph with XML, but how to implement it with java code?

**Fragment XML definition without "app:navGraph" attribute:**

> ```
> <fragment
>     android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
>     android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     app:defaultNavHost="true"
>     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
>     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
> />
>
> <!-- app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" -->
> ```

**TestActivity.java**

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

// How to pass the Class argument into the getNavigator?
NavGraph navGraph = new NavGraph(navController.getNavigatorProvider().getNavigator(???));
```

**Question: 
How to create a new NavGraph object here? 
Which navigatorClass should be used as the argument of method "getNavigator(Class)"?**

**androidx.navigation.NavigatorProvider.java**

```
/**
 * Retrieves a registered {@link Navigator} using the name provided by the
 * {@link Navigator.Name Navigator.Name annotation}.
 *
 * @param navigatorClass class of the navigator to return
 * @return the registered navigator with the given {@link Navigator.Name}
 *
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the Navigator does not have a
 * {@link Navigator.Name Navigator.Name annotation}
 * @throws IllegalStateException if the Navigator has not been added
 *
 * @see #addNavigator(Navigator)
 */
@NonNull
public final <T extends Navigator<?>> T getNavigator(@NonNull Class<T> navigatorClass) {
    String name = getNameForNavigator(navigatorClass);
    return getNavigator(name);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50899344/10735178

Comment: Thanks @Askar, that link is inflate NavGraph with XML definition. I found this link from "developer.android.com" but it uses Kotlin to build NavGraph programmatically instead of Java. I don't understand with the Kotlin code inside. Please help to check and see how to convert it to Java. Thanks. The link: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-kotlin-dsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see java code here:

```
NavHostFragment myNavHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) findViewById(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment);
NavInflater inflater = myNavHostFragment.getNavController().getNavInflater();
NavGraph graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.my_nav_graph);
myNavHostFragment.getNavController().setGraph(graph);
```

Comment: Get it now. Thanks for your help.