# Navigation Architecture Component- Passing argument data to the startDestination with Fragment

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have a `fragment A` which contains this code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    .......

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/children_container"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/layout_navigation" />

    .......

</RelativeLayout>
```

that start my `fragment B`. I would like to know how I can pass some argument from `fragmentA` and get in my `fragmentB`.

By reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334550/navigation-architecture-component-passing-argument-data-to-the-startdestination) but its talked about Activity A from Activity B.

I tried to remove this line from my FragmentContainerView

```
app:navGraph="@navigation/layout_navigation"
```

And in my `fragmentA` I added this following line :

```
val bundle = Bundle().apply {
    putString(KEY, "value")
}

NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.layout_navigation, bundle)
```

In my `fragment B`, my `arguments` is null

Do you have any idea?

Comment: `NavHostFragment.create(R.navigation.layout_navigation, bundle)` I don't understand this line at all. You should be using `Navigation.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.some_destination, bundle)`.

Comment: for some reason I had to do this .. : `val fragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.children_container) ?: return`

`val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(fragment)`

Then it works ...